# Convert String to Time format Apex

Tags: apex, lightning

1) I have a lighting input of time.

2) I use JS to get the value of this field.

```
component.find("timeChange1").get("v.value")
```

3) I want to call an apex class to update the time when this JS function is run.

4) However, the format I send the time in, is string due to JS.

Question) Is it possible to convert a string to a "time" only format not date time. If so how?

`<lightning:input type="time" name="time1"  aura:id="timeChange1" label="Preferred first chasing Time" value= "{!v.firstTime}"/>`

5) Value of variable being passed to apex '18:00'

6) Apex Class

```
    public static void updateTime(String recordId, time timeChange){
      Lead obj = new Lead();
      obj = [select Monday__c, Tuesday__c,  Wednesday__c, Thursday__c, Friday__c, Saturday__c, First_Chasing_Time__c, Second_Chasing_Time__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = : recordId LIMIT 1]; 
      obj.First_Chasing_Time__c = timeChange;
      update obj;
```

Comment: can you add the apex class?

Comment: Added the apex class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the time is always going to be in the format of 'HH:mm' you can convert the String '16:00' to a [Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_time.htm) like this:

```
public static void updateTime(String recordId, String strTimeChange){

  String[] strTimeSplit = strTimeChange.split(':');
  Time timeChange = Time.newInstance( Integer.valueOf(strTimeSplit[0]) //hour
                                     ,Integer.valueOf(strTimeSplit[1]) //min
                                     ,0                                //sec
                                     ,0);                              //ms
```

```
obj.First_Chasing_Time__c = timeChange;
update obj;
```

You should probably add some error handling to your use case.

If you can handle the timechange in JS and pass a formatted string to your apex class there are several [datetime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) methods that are easier to use.

for example: `DateTime.parse(String);`

Comment: Thanks, sorted my issue.

Comment: No Problem, if that answered your question / helped, please mark as best answer!